# How to check if two or more conditions are met vs only one of them is true?

Tags: vbscript

I'm using the following script with a software which reads a CheckBox using OMR and outputs the data to an XML file.

Is there a way I can change it to say if more than one box has been checked, the data output should be the first checked box in the list?

Hope this makes sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim installer 

q_a1= Metadata.Values("OMR_FRED_P2")
q_a2= Metadata.Values("OMR_JON_P2")
q_a3= Metadata.Values("OMR_MATT_P2")
q_a4= Metadata.Values("OMR_STEVE_P2") 

If q_a1 = "Filled" Then
  installer = "Fred"
End If
If q_a2 = "Filled" then
  installer = "Jon"
End If
If q_a3 = "Filled" then
  installer = "Matt"
End If
If q_a4 = "Filled" then
  installer = "Steve"
End If

call Metadata.SetValues("CompleteBy",installer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Dim a1Checked, a2Checked, a3Checked, a4Checked
Dim numberOfChecked

a1Checked = (q_a1 = "Filled")
a2Checked = (q_a2 = "Filled")
a3Checked = (q_a3 = "Filled")
a4Checked = (q_a4 = "Filled")

numberOfChecked = Abs(a1Checked + a2Checked + a3Checked + a4Checked)

If a1Checked Or numberOfChecked > 1 Then
    installer = "Fred"
ElseIf a2Checked Then
    installer = "Jon"
ElseIf a3Checked Then
    installer = "Matt"
ElseIf a4Checked Then
    installer = "Steve"
Else
    ' Decide what you want to do if none is checked.
End If

Call Metadata.SetValues("CompleteBy", installer)
```

In VBScript, the numeric value of a "boolean true" value is `-1` and of the false value is `0`.

The above code simply adds the values together. If two conditions are met, the total would be `-2`, then we use the `Abs` function to get the abstract value (i.e., returning 2 instead of -2). After that, you can easily check if two or more conditions are met by using `numberofChecked > 1`.

Comment: Wow, that looks brilliant. Thank you very much. I will give it a go and update you. I must admit I didn't think about none being checked, I suppose the output could be 'not filled' rather than the software just reporting an error and then the workflow would still process.